# how to tile a single cloned image graphic magic

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, graphicsmagick

I would like to create an image with a single image tiled in width and height with graphicsmagick .

I tried this command which work :

```
gm montage -geometry 2x2 mypic.png mypic.png mypic.png out.png
```

However, I would like to repeat this pattern image a great number of time (over 100x100).

**Is it possible to make that without repeating `mypic.png` 10000 times ?** ?

Answer (score 4):

I do not know GraphicsMagick. But I assume it is similar to ImageMagick, since it was a spin-off from ImageMagick. In ImageMagick, you can do that easily in two ways:

Input:

[image]

```
montage lena.jpg -duplicate 24 -tile 5x5 -geometry +0+0 result.jpg
```

[image]

```
convert -size 1280x1280 tile:lena.jpg result2.jpg
```

[image]

See the various ways to do tiling at https://imagemagick.org/Usage/canvas/#tile

I am not sure if GraphicsMagick has -duplicate, since that was introduce in ImageMagick 6.6.8-10 3/27/2011 long after they split-off.

ImageMagick has many more features than GraphicsMagick, but may be slightly slower. You may want to consider using ImageMagick rather than GraphicMagick

Comment: The two are not the same and have different features and syntax. So you may have to work with ImageMagick, unless someone else can give you an equivalent command for GraphicsMagick. I suspect GraphicsMagick does not have -duplicate. GraphicsMagick is an early spin off of ImageMagick and stopped development. Whereas, ImageMagick has continued development of new features and improvement.

Answer (score 3):

You don't say how large the images you are planning to make are, but if they are very large, you could run into a couple of issues.

First, JPEG is limited to 65536 x 65536 pixels, so you'll need something like bigtiff or PNG if you need larger than that.

Secondly, you can need huge amounts of memory to compose large images. For example, on this laptop I can run:

```
$ time convert -size 50000x50000 tile:k2.jpg result.jpg
real    6m11.366s
user    1m19.671s
sys 0m20.836s
```

to makes a 50k x 50k pixel JPG in about 6m.

`convert` will assemble the whole image before it starts writing the result. If you don't have bucketloads of RAM, it'll use a huge temporary file instead. If I look in `/tmp` during processing, I see:

```
$ ls -l /tmp
total 1199684
-rw------- 1 john john 20000000000 Dec  1 15:56 magick-9559WtN2jwPlvrMm
```

A 20gb temporary file. That's 50000 * 50000 * 4 * 2, so it's making a 16-bit, four channel temporary image. Because `convert` is spending all its time blocked in disc IO, it's rather slow.

You could consider other systems -- [libvips](https://libvips.github.io/libvips/) is a streaming image processing library, so it can execute commands like this without having to make complete intermediate images. I see:

```
$ time vips replicate k2.jpg result.jpg 35 25
real    0m13.592s
user    0m16.383s
sys 0m1.426s
$ vipsheader result.jpg 
result.jpg: 50750x51200 uchar, 3 bands, srgb, jpegload
```

That's copying `k2.jpg` 35 times horizontally and 25 times vertically to make an image slightly larger than 50k x 50k. It does not make a temporary file, and finishes in about 15 seconds. It'll have no problems going to very, very large output images -- I regularly process images of 300,000 x 300,000 pixels (though not in jpg format, obviously).

Comment: Good points to consider with potential large output image, John!